# On OAuth2 and when using authorization_code. How do you know which user is requestion access?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

I am creating an OAuth2 flow. I already created the /authenticate endpoint to ensure the user accepts the app.

My question comes here: What is the best approach to know which user is accepting the access, should I just read from the incoming username/password (before the accept button)? Additionally, would you all always use a username/password for this case? Or is there any other better way to authenticate the user?

I am not sure this question needs code since is more about theory than coding.

Thanks.

Comment: אto make it clear: you write the authentication server? (or the resource server?)

Comment: what other way you have to identify the user except the username he enters? you have the answer :)

Comment: @OhadR So, is normal to also send the username while sending the /authorize request?